# NextJS passing id of record to a function with a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following NextJS component which renders a list of people .. I also have a delete button which opens a modal and asks if you want to delete said person, but i cant figure out how to pass the id to the function through the modal so its not working at all.

```
const peoples = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Scott'}
    { id: 2, name: 'Luke'}
    { id: 3, name: 'Hannah'}
    { id: 4, name: 'Reg'}
]

const Peoples = () => {
    const [confirmPersonDeleteModal, setConfirmPersonDeleteModal] = useState(false)

    const handleDeletePerson = () => {
        console.log('Deleting')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ConfirmModal
                open={confirmPersonDeleteModal}
                onClose={() => setConfirmPersonDeleteModal(false)}
                title="Delete Person" 
                onConfirm={handleDeletePerson}
            >
                Are you sure you want to delete this person?
            </ConfirmModal>


            {peoples.map((people) => (
                <>
                    <p>{people.name} - {people.id}</p>
                    <a onClick={() => setConfirmPersonDeleteModal(true)}>Delete</a>

                </>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default Peoples
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to achieve this is to create a state in which you will store the selected user :

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const [selectedUser,setSelectedUser] = useState({}); // we initialize the state with an empty object
```

The advantage of storing the whole user object and not only the id is that this will be usefull to output user informations insidethe modal or even if you want to create another modal maybe for updating the user so you have all the user informations in your `selectedUser` state

To test this, let's also make `peoples` a useState hook so we can see the component updates each time one element of `pepoles` is deleted :

```js
const [peoples, setPeoples] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Scott" },
    { id: 2, name: "Luke" },
    { id: 3, name: "Hannah" },
    { id: 4, name: "Reg" },
]);
```

Now when the button is clicked you set `isOpen` to `true` and `selectedUser` to the selected user :

```js
{peoples.map((people) => (
<Fragment key={people.id}> {/* don't miss key property here */}
  <p>
    {people.name} - {people.id}
  </p>
  <a
    onClick={() => {
      setIsOpen(true);
      setSelectedUser(people);
    }}
  >
    Delete
  </a>
</Fragment>
))}
```

So once the button is clicked since state is updated the component rerenders and `<ConfirmModal>` will recieve the new values of `isOpen` and `selectedUser` :

```js
<ConfirmModal
  open={isOpen}
  onClose={handleClose}
  onConfirm={handleConfirm}
  selectedUser={selectedUser}
  title="Delete Person"
>
  Are you sure you want to delete this person?
</ConfirmModal>
```

The `handleClose` function is to manage stuff when the modal is closed :

```js
const handleClose = () => {
setIsOpen(false);
setSelectedUser({}) // this is optional you can leave the selectedUser as it is since the modal only opens when the button is clicked so when selectedUser is updated 
}
```

The `handleConfirm` is for deleting the selectedUser from `peoples` :

```js
const handleConfirm = () => {
  const newPeoples = peoples.filter((people) => people.id !== selectedUser.id); // looping through peoples items and return every item if it does not have the same id of selectedUser so newPeoples will receive all items of peoples except the selectedUser
  setPeoples(newPeoples); //update state
  setIsOpen(false); // close the modal after deleting user
};
```

## Full working example :

```js
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Peoples() {
  const [peoples, setPeoples] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Scott" },
    { id: 2, name: "Luke" },
    { id: 3, name: "Hannah" },
    { id: 4, name: "Reg" },
  ]);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({});
  //
  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    setSelectedUser({}); // this is optional you can leave the selectedUser as it is since the modal only opens when the button is clicked so when selectedUser is updated
  };

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    const newPeoples = peoples.filter(
      (people) => people.id !== selectedUser.id
    );
    setPeoples(newPeoples);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ConfirmModal
        open={isOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        selectedUser={selectedUser}
        title="Delete Person"
      >
        Are you sure you want to delete this person?
      </ConfirmModal>

      {peoples.map((people) => (
        <Fragment key={people.id}>
          <p>
            {people.name} - {people.id}
          </p>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIsOpen(true);
              setSelectedUser(people);
            }}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
// ConfirmModal component (sorry for the ugly styling)
const ConfirmModal = ({ open, onClose, onConfirm, selectedUser, title }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {open ? (
        <div>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <h2> This is the user to delete :</h2>
          <p>user name : {selectedUser.name}</p>
          <p>user id : {selectedUser.id}</p>
          <button onClick={onConfirm}>Delete User</button>
          <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <hr></hr>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the id of the person with the setConfirmPersonDeleteModal.

```js
const peoples = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Scott'}
    { id: 2, name: 'Luke'}
    { id: 3, name: 'Hannah'}
    { id: 4, name: 'Reg'}
]

const Peoples = () => {
    const [confirmPersonDeleteModal, setConfirmPersonDeleteModal] = useState({isOpen: false, id: null})

    const handleDeletePerson = () => {
        console.log('Deleting user with id', confirmPersonDeleteModal?.id) //you can pass the id to the handleDeletePerson function
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ConfirmModal
                open={confirmPersonDeleteModal?.isOpen}
                onClose={() => setConfirmPersonDeleteModal({isOpen: false, id: null})}
                title="Delete Person" 
                onConfirm={handleDeletePerson}
            >
                Are you sure you want to delete this person?
            </ConfirmModal>


            {peoples.map((people) => (
                <>
                    <p>{people.name} - {people.id}</p>
                    <a onClick={() => setConfirmPersonDeleteModal({isOpen: true, id: people?.id})}>Delete</a>

                </>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default Peoples
```

Answer (score 0):

From the reference of your code, I got the Idea that you created a function for deletion i.e handleDeletePerson().
Following solution might help you :

1. You should not make this function on OnConfirm of modal otherwise you won't be able to pick Id of that particular person.
2. You may create a button like this, so you would be able pass the Id;

   ```
   <a onClick={() => {           
        setConfirmPersonDeleteModal(true)               
        handleDeletePerson(people.id) 
   }>
     Delete
   </a>
   ```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, I am a bit unsure on it though ... Is there any chance you could give me a code example?

Comment: This Link might help you : https://www.freakyjolly.com/pass-data-open-react-modal-from-parent-functional-component/ Sorry, But I can't find more particular example for it.