# React - redirect page to show data modifications?

Tags: reactjs

I am not a React user but have a question about how an HTML table is normally refreshed after record operations such as UPDATE, DELETE or CREATE.  For example, we may have a table like this:

```
[New Record]
John    john@mydomain.com   [Edit] [Delete]
Jane    jane@mydomain.com   [Edit] [Delete]
```

If the ‘Edit’ button is pressed, a dialog with a form appears that allows you to modify that record.  When saved, how do you update the table?  I don't need to see code, I'd just like to know what most people do.

I saw a React video where the developer redirected to the page like this:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
...
navigate(‘/’);
```

To me, this seems simple and effective but a waste of resources because you rebuild the whole page.

My questions:

1. Is this the popular way to handle this situation in React?
2. How about writing some code and rebuilding the table but not the whole page?
3. How about writing some code that updates the specific row?

The first option seems to be the easiest approach by far since you don’t have to write any extra code.  The second option seems to take a little extra code but more resource friendly.  The third option takes the most developer effort but this would only target the specific row, e.g. delete or update it.

I would just like to hear your thoughts on this, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you create a state to hold the table data and another boolean state to control the ui.
when the user clicks on the button to add a new record you toggle your second state so the component rerender and based on this state, in the JSX, you decide either to show the table or the form where you can add a new record.
then when you add the record you update the table state of course and also toggle the other state so the component rerenders and the updated table is displayed in the ui.
to update a specific row you can create another sate(default `null`) in which you will store the selected row if "Edit" is clicked, you update this state with the selected row (element of the map iteration) and with same logic, if this state is `!== null` then you show the update form in which you can get advatage of the state to display the old row data and after you update it, you update the whole table state then set the third state to `null` so the component rerenders, and again the updated table is displayed in the ui

Comment: Excellent answer, I had a hard time deciding the best answer, this one or Yuu.  Wish I could give both the best answer, very helpful, both!

Comment: @user1643244 have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75622439/nextjs-passing-id-of-record-to-a-function-with-a-modal/75646392#75646392) it may help

Answer (score 2):

1.- No, it is only a way to do that but not the only one, you can refresh the table without any redirection

2.- Yes it is possible, the table is linked to a state (table data), once the state is updated the whole table will change

3.- Each edit and delete has to have a handler (click) which you pass the id (id of the specific registration/record that you get when populate the table) and update the table data state with that id, once you trigger that state change the table in the UI will update too

---

Extra

Regarding HTML, react uses virtual DOM (Document Object Model) that is the model or representation of the browser elements in the UI

Imagine this like javascript registration of actual browser DOM so when you update states it generates another virtual DOM with the changes

After that in a process called reconcilliation it updates in the most efficient way the real DOM based on those changes, this process exists because real DOM manipulation is very slow.

More on this here:
[https://medium.com/javarevisited/react-reconciliation-algorithm-86e3e22c1b40#:~:text=The%20reconciliation%20process%20ensures%20that,the%20state%20of%20the%20application](https://medium.com/javarevisited/react-reconciliation-algorithm-86e3e22c1b40#:%7E:text=The%20reconciliation%20process%20ensures%20that,the%20state%20of%20the%20application).

Hope it helps